# Difference between SHVZK and HVZK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

What is the difference between Special Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge (SHVZK) and Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge (HVZK)? Sometimes I see one term being used, other times the other. Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge is a particular case of Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge; that is, if a protocol satisfies SHVZK, it satisfies HVZK. SHVZK has been introduced to simplify discussions about $\Sigma$-protocols. In $\Sigma$-protocols, HVZK is typically proven as follows: fix an arbitrary challenge $e$, and show that it is possible to efficiently generate a random transcript $(c, e', a)$ for a $\Sigma$-protocol, conditioned on $e = e'$. If such a simulator can be exhibited, then the $\Sigma$-protocol is clearly HVZK. The term SHVZK refers to $\Sigma$-protocols where this particular condition holds.

Note that similarly, the term special soundness is generally used to refer to a sufficient property for the soundness of a $\Sigma$-protocol (typically, that given two transcripts $(c,e,a)$ and $(c,e',a')$ for the same $c$, it is possible to extract a witness efficiently), which is typically satisfies by most $\Sigma$-protocols. Each time, "special XXX" simply means "a specific notion which is sufficient for XXX".

Comment: Thank you, @Geoffroy Couteau! Btw, is there any literature (book, paper, etc) that introduces and explains in an intermediate level the different approaches to security proofs in cryptography?

Comment: Hmm, maybe? Unfortunately, I'm not really aware of the basic crypto books and teaching documents, I never used any myself (I learned by reading research articles), and "security proofs in cryptography" is an extremely vast subject. Lindell's [tutorial on simulation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf) is one important example that comes to mind about the simulation technique, a very general and important proof method. The paper might provide other pointers. I am also personally fond of Goldreich's books (Foundations of Cryptography Vol. 1 & 2), but some find them hard to read.

Comment: Ty, @Geoffroy Couteau! Yes, I am also learning by reading research articles. But its not easy when the information is disperse and sometimes even looks contradicting. I think there is a need for a central piece of information at intermediate level that serves as a general guide for "security proofs in cryptography" to attract more new people to the field, not only the smart ones :p maybe I'll write one myself!